# How to shorten a long JSON path into a variable in a AngularJS ng-repeat loop?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In an `ng-repeat` loop I'm using multiple times a longer object properties path, where mostly only the last segment is different:

```
<div id="projects" ng-app="portfolio">
    <div id="projectsList" ng-controller="ProjectsListController as projectsList">
        <div class="projectItem" ng-repeat="projectItem in projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.projects">
            <div class="project-image">
                <img
                    ng-src="{{projectItem._embedded.images[0].src}}"
                    title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                    alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{projectItem._embedded.images[0].title}}"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to use a variable instead of `projectItem._embedded.images[0]` (well, in this case the path length might be acceptable, but sometimes it becomes ver long). **How use a variable (`var myVar = projectItem._embedded.images[0]`) instead of the object properties path?**

---

**EDIT**

Just to explain, what I mean -- in PHP I would implement it like this:

```
<div id="projects">
    <div id="projectsList">
    <?php foreach ($projectsList['projectsListData']['_embedded']['projects'] as $projectItem) :?>
        <!-- This intermediate step is missing in the AngularJS loop. -->
        <?php $image = $projectItem['_embedded']['images'][0]; ?>
        <div class="projectItem">
            <div class="project-image">
                <img
                    src="<?php echo $image['src']; ?>"
                    title="<?php echo $projectItem['title']; ?> - <?php echo $image['title']; ?>"
                    alt="<?php echo $projectItem['title']; ?> - <?php echo $image['title']; ?>"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.project in the controller to project as in the example below, then call `projectsList.project` in the view:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ProjectsListController', ProjectsListController)

function ProjectsListController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.project = projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.project;
}
```

Comment: `projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.project` is not the problem -- I already replace it with a short `projectItem`. But I want also additionally use a shorter string for the segments between the begin of the path and the last part, e.g. `myVar` instead of `projectItem._embedded.images[0]` (see the PHP example in my question update).

Answer (score 0):

Use ngInit to alias a property of your item in the ngRepeat.

```
 <div id="projects" ng-app="portfolio">
        <div id="projectsList" ng-controller="ProjectsListController as projectsList">
            <div class="projectItem" 
                 ng-repeat="projectItem in projectsList.projectsListData._embedded.project" 
                 ng-init="image=projectItem._embedded.images[0]">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img 
                       ng-src="{{image.src}}"
                       title="{{projectItem.title}} - {{image.title}}"
                       alt="{{projectItem.title}} - {{image.title}}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Something like this should work.

Here's a fiddle with a little sample I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/7f83hLd9/6/

Comment: It doesn't work and I think it cannot work, since the "variables" `{{src}}` and `{{title}}` are not defined.

Comment: @automatix Yah, you're right. I thought it would but I tested it and it won't. See my updated answer for your solution. I included a fiddle as well with an example.